# Focus switching to the wrong program after closing form

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms

I have a program that has a lot of forms built into it and normally there are multiple forms open. But when you close out of a form or just do `Me.Close` in a form, it deselects it and select something else. For example, when using the program on top of Google Chrome and closing out of the form that used the message box, it will select the Chrome window, moving Chrome on top of everything.

How can I fix this?

Comment: If this isn’t .NET, please feel free to change the tags to [tag:vb6].

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear.  Are you saying that your application has multiple forms open and, when you close the active form, instead of activating another form in your app, a window in another app is activated instead?  If so, does the same thing happen regardless of the combination of forms open and the one closed or does it just happen for a particular combination?  Does the same thing happen in a new project?

Comment: Yes that is exactly what is happening and it happens with every ingle application and the pattern that i seen so fair is that when a form display a message box it works but when you close the form Windows focus a different application like chrome or notepad or visual studio

Comment: This is not an unusual problem, it happens when you hide or disable windows yourself.  For a split second, after closing the active window, your program may have no window that can be activated.  Windows is forced to find another window to activate, that will be one of another process.  You fix it by unhiding or re-enabling the window *before* the active window is gone, the FormClosing event is good for that.  Displaying dialogs on another thread causes it as well.  Clearly you need to better document your question to get a reliable guess.

Comment: But hans passant i did that before my main form is form1 so normally i would have done form1.show() to show it on top of everything and it doesn't work that way, ill try BringToFront action as soon as i can

Answer (score 0):

Well you can use the **BringToFront**, **TopMost = True** or **Focus** method for this, for example

```
Form2.BringToFront
Me.Close
```

as simple as that =D , use it for multiple forms if you want all of them to be on top.